# Why Can Variables Start With # In Julia Macro Name Mangling?

Tags: julia

I'm just learning macros and I'm confused about how it's possible for a variable name to start with a #, but that is exactly what a macro seems to successfully do.  For example, if I want to set a variable to equal 4:

```
macro testMacro(sym)
  esym = esc(sym)
  quote
    temp = 4
    $esym = temp
    return
  end
end
```

Then

```
julia> macroexpand(:(@testMacro α))
quote  # none, line 4:
    #132#temp = 4 # line 5:
    α = #132#temp # line 6:
    return
end

julia> @testMacro α

julia> α
4
```

Notice the temp variable is named #132#temp and it's my understanding that it will be evaluated in the REPL just like that.  However, that seems impossible since that whole line should now technically be a comment.

If I look at the first expression within the macro, I get something that I cannot reproduce.

```
julia> macroexpand(:(@testMacro α)).args[2]
:(#132#temp = 4)

julia> ex = :(#132#temp = 4)


ERROR: syntax: incomplete: premature end of input
```

What's going on here?  I suppose I fundamentally have two questions. 1.) If it's possible, how can I define a variable (even within an expression) that starts with a #?  2.) Assuming the existence of such a variable, how does julia manage to not treat it as a comment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What's going on here?

The name-mangling here is to preserve [macro hygiene](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/metaprogramming/#hygiene) so that names defined within a macro don't conflict with other names in the environment. (it is possible to override this using `esc`)

> 1.) If it's possible, how can I define a variable (even within an expression) that starts with a #?

I'm not sure why you would want to do this because accessing the variable will be cumbersome. But it is possible:

```
julia> eval(Expr(:(=), symbol("#s"), 1))
1

julia> whos()
#s                            Int64
Base                          Module
Core                          Module
LastMain                      Module
Main                          Module
ans                           Int64

julia> eval(symbol("#s"))
1
```

> 2.) Assuming the existence of such a variable, how does julia manage to not treat it as a comment?

Comments are dropped at the parser level, so the rest of the system never actually sees them. As shown above, a Symbol can be created from an arbitrary string containing a `#`, which is what the macro code does internally.